# Mysql Table row add not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with standard text fields. I have created a table that duplicates with the help of this http://phpmysqlmania.blogspot.com/p/dynamic-table-row-inserter.html. I have it posting to Mysql Ok. but the issue that it only posts 1 line. The addition table goes nowhere.

I have simplified the code (Very long)
Here is my code:

JS

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentItem = 1;
    $('#addnew').click(function(){
        currentItem++;
        $('#items').val(currentItem);
        var strToAdd = '<tr><th colspan="100%"></th></tr><tr><tr><th>Type</th><th>Description</th><tr><td align="center"><select name="typeofunit'+currentItem+'" id="typeofunit'+currentItem+'" ><option value="DX">DX</option><option value="Chiller">Chiller</option></select></td><td align="center"><input name="unitdescription'+currentItem+'" id="unitdescription'+currentItem+'"></td></tr>';
        $('#data').append(strToAdd);

    });
});
```

index.php

```
<form action="function.php" method="post">                                
<table>
<tr><th>Company Name</th><th>Street</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Zip</th><th>Country</th>    </th></tr>
<td><input type="text" id="company" name="company" ></td>
<td><input  id="street" name="street" ></td>
</table>
<br>
<table>  

<table>
<tr><th>DX or Chiller</th><th>Equipment Description</th></tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
    <select name="typeofunit1” id="typeofunit1” >
            <option value="DX">DX</option>
            <option value="Chiller">Chiller</option>
            </select>
</td>            
<td align="center">
        <input name="unitdescription1” id="unitdescription1”>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

                                <input type="button" id="addnew" name="addnew" value="Add  Another Unit" /> 
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

function.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","ptgpfaso_root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);
for( $i = 0 ; $i <= $count; $i++ )
{
$company = $_POST['company'];
$street = $_POST['street'];
$typeofunit = $_POST['typeofunit' . ($i+1)];
$unitdescription = $_POST['unitdescription' . ($i+1)];

$sql = "INSERT INTO equips (company,street,typeofunit,unitdescription,)
VALUES
('".$company."',
'".$street."',
'".$typeofunit."',     
'".$unitdescription."',

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
 {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }
echo " Submitted to MySQL ";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: **SQL injection risk ahead!** Please read about prepared statements. The way your code is written makes it vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Besides that, you added an unnecesary comma at the end of the value list of the `insert`, and forgot to close the parenthesis of the value list.

Answer (score 0):

You have added extra `,` in insert query like `unitdescription,` and `'".$unitdescription."',`  and not properly close `)` the query as well.

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO equips (company,street,typeofunit,unitdescription)
    VALUES
   ('".$company."',
   '".$street."',
   '".$typeofunit."',     
   '".$unitdescription."');
```

instead of

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO equips (company,street,typeofunit,unitdescription,)
    VALUES
   ('".$company."',
   '".$street."',
   '".$typeofunit."',
 '".$unitdescription."',
```

Also,

```
 for( $i = 0 ; $i < $count; $i++ )
 ------------------^
```

instead of

```
for( $i = 0 ; $i <= $count; $i++ )
```

**Note:** Use mysqli_* function or PDO instead of using mysql_* functions(deprecated)

Comment: should probably get rid of the comma after `unitdescription,` too.

Comment: This solves the OP question... but leaves the SQL injection vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
$company = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company']);
$street = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['street']);
$typeofunit = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['typeofunit' . ($i+1)]); 
$unitdescription = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['unitdescription' . ($i+1)]);

$sql = "INSERT INTO equips (company,street,typeofunit,unitdescription) 
        VALUES ('$company', '$street', '$typeofunit', '$unitdescription')";
```

That'll fix your code. Although it is not advisable to use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated.

Your mistakes :

Mistake 1 : You haven't closed the double quotes which you opened right before `INSERT`.
Mistake 2 : You haven't used the closing bracket at the end of your `VALUES`.
Mistake 3 : You have put an extra comma after `unitdescription` in your `INSERT()` query.

Also, have you initialized the `$count` variable?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have fixed the typos. But still not working...$count variable?

Comment: Make an edit to the question with your current code! Also, try running the query in your localhost's SQL with dummy data and see if it works.